# C++ CLI(MSVisual CLR) Input from text file

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I'm trying to input 2 numbers form a text file that is selected, inside the text file it is "2 5" everything seems to work, but when I do (which I bet is completely wrong) in the debug menu it says the right number but then changes to `-1`. So I'd like to know what is the right way to input from file onto an integer?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
                 filePathDuom = textBox1->Text; 


            String^ FDuom = filePathDuom;
            StreamReader ^Duom = File::OpenText(FDuom);
            String^ line;
            while((line = Duom->ReadLine()) !=nullptr)
            {
            x1 = Duom->Read();
            y1 = Duom->Read();
            }
            x3 = x1 + y1;
            textBox12->Text = x3.ToString();

            Duom->Close();

}



private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        MessageBox::Show("Pasirinkite Faila");
        OpenFileDialog^ failas = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
        failas->Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        if( failas->ShowDialog() != System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
        {
            return;
        }
        textBox1->Text = ( failas->FileName );
         }

};
}
```

Comment: I will leave the [indentation part](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47100612/edit) to you.

Comment: If you read a line from the text file and that line contains `"2 5"`, then the subsequent `Read`s on the stream *cannot* read `2` or `5` unless they occur again. *Also*, `Read` reads a character ASCII value, not an integer value from the string representation.

Comment: The Read() calls are nonsensical, you already read the line with ReadLine().  They'll consume two characters from the start of the line, eventually hitting end-of-file and returning -1.  Delete them and use String::Split and Int32.Parse() instead.